# How to find an new element recently added on webpage dynamically after drag and drop in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop, webdriver

[image]

Currently I am working on a webpage which has rappid js components. I am trying to achieve dragging and dropping of elements from the palette as seen in the screenshot to the grid. The element I drag from the palette can identified using its model id. The minute I drop the element a copy of it gets created on the grid its model id changes. The id seen in the dom also gets added dynamically. There will be multiple elements on the grid which have the same attributes as seen in the screenshot.

How to find this element uniquely and dynamically?

I have tried using Sikuli, but it doesn't help as there will be multiple similar looking elements. I can get all the elements on the grid using findElements() but no way to compare the recently dropped element. All I am trying to achieve is finding the element uniquely after it is dropped on the grid so that I can further perform operations on it.

Can we reverse the process of finding an element? from the location of the mouse cursor find the element?

[image]

Comment: Have answered it, please check and let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi @user765, after doing the drag and drop, where the copy gets created - it is always at the end or in between?

Comment: @AliCSE i pass x,y co-ordinates to the drag drop method

Comment: Ok, I'm asking about the html source code. Where the new `model-id` gets created, always at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be two ways to get the last added element:

1. From the div structure mentioned in the screenshot, i can see that the attribute "id" is getting incremented like "j_57" and "j_59", so every new item on the page would be having an id after it has been added on the page.

   So what you can do here is you can fetch the id list and get the last element just before adding your element on the webpage and then fetch the id list again and check the last element, that element would be the element which you have added on the page and you can verify it by checking its "j_" number that it has incremented from the last value.
2. If the currently added element gets added in the last of the div structure, then you can perform the drag and drop and can directly get the last element using xpath `//g`.

Code for 1st point should be like:

```
    //Fetch the elements before doing the operation
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//g[contains(@id,'j_')]"));
    // You would be getting the last value present by using getAttribute
    String lastElement = elements.get(elements.size()-1).getAttribute("id");
    
    //Perform the drag and drop operation now
    
    //Fetch the elements again
    List<WebElement> newElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//g[contains(@id,'j_')]"));
    // Fetch the id attribute again and verify that the j count has incremented and then you can fetch the last element, which is your new element now 
    String newLastElement = newElements.get(elements.size()-1).getAttribute("id");
    // Your new element can be found using
    WebElement requiredElement = newElements.get(elements.size()-1);
    String modelId = requiredElement.getAttribute("model-id");
```

Code for the 2nd point should be like:

```
    //Perform the drag and drop and then fetch the element list
    List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//g"));
    // Fetching the last element in the list        
    WebElement lastElement = elementList.get(elementList.size()-1);
    String modelId = lastElement.getAttribute("model-id");
```

Both the ways are correct, if your j_ values are increment on adding the elements then you can be sure of the new element by checking the j_ incremented value from the first approach. Else second approach is short and sweet and would work fine as well.

Comment: Yes, please check and if it helps, then please upvote and accept the answer :)

Comment: @user765 hey, did it help you ? if yes, then please upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: hey, yes thanks it worked with elementList.get(elementList.size()), -1 was returning the second last item. :)

Comment: Great !! Happy to help :)